# Is there a way to select first column from first row and add second column values to it for all remaining rows?

Tags: sql

So I'm working with MS SQL and I have a selection table:

| total | margin | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 45 | -1 | 2022-01 |
| 45 | 0 | 2022-02 |
| 45 | 0 | 2022-03 |
| 45 | 1 | 2022-04 |
| 45 | -1 | 2022-05 |
| 45 | 0 | 2022-06 |

What I need is to select firt total and add margin for each other months ignoring other totals like so:

| total | margin | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 44 | -1 | 2022-01 |
| 44 | 0 | 2022-02 |
| 44 | 0 | 2022-03 |
| 45 | 1 | 2022-04 |
| 44 | -1 | 2022-05 |
| 44 | 0 | 2022-06 |

I've tried using LAG function but it ignores last change. For example at forth row it would take previous value of 45 and not 44.

Thanks for answers got what I need with:
first_value(total) over(order by [date] ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) + sum(margin) over(order by [date] ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) as total

Comment: `first_value(total) over(order by date) + sum(margin) over(order by date rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)`?

Comment: Please describe what would be a result if `margin` value is equal to `1` for all the rows in the above dataset. It's not clear what to do with the second `margin`, because you add current `margin` to the previous row, but for the second row the rule is different.

Comment: Sorry did a mistake on second table at first row it should be 44 as it adds whats on the margin column

Comment: Then the first comment is an answer, just remove `...rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding` as long as `order by something` implies `rows between unbounded preceding and current row` as a window boundary in all DBMS